# cvs complaining about the -m option when trying to commit

Tags: cvs

I have been stumped on this for the 2 days now. What a waste of time.
When I do `cvs -H commit` the -m option is there

When I check the history of commands on our linux box, so many programmers have executed the same command and they swear it has worked

[Checking google - ONE person seems to have an issue, posted it on forum and it has NO solution see](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji_p6e-7H4AhWDgVwKHVs7A6MQFnoECD4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cvsnt.org%2Fpipermail%2Fcvsnt%2F2008-September%2F031234.html&usg=AOvVaw19XYI-YrOD0Yc8GlSfR3Lw)

Am I doing something so maddeningly so dumb ? Please help me.

```
cvs -d :something:mycvs_srv:/cvs/repo commit -f –m "bug fix" ctxroot/path/to/code.txt
cvs commit: nothing known about `–m'
cvs commit: nothing known about `bug fix'
cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!
```

Version details

```
Client: Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)
Server: Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)
```

Comment: I have managed to get it to work by dropping the -m option.
When you do that cvs opens a vim editor temp file for you to put in your commit message
But, that is not an acceptable answer for my question. This should work as is.
Unless, this is bug in CVS

Comment: Are you typing it or is it cut and paste? I just wonder if it is accidentally an em-dash rather than a dash that's in there.

Comment: "Note that [`-f` in `cvs commit`] is not the standard behavior of the ‘-f’ option as defined in Section A.5 [Common options], page 90. Force cvs to commit a new revision even if you haven’t made any changes to the file." Which is perhaps not what you wanted anyway?

Comment: @Mort Thank You for pointing out the finer point in the use of -f during a commit. Will drop the use of it in the future to see how CVS responds. btw - checked am not using a dash that looks like em-dash.